# 2 different link styles show ok in IE but not in other browsers. When link clicked all links show visited

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My website is here for testing purposes:
http://www.splithorizont.com/itc/web1.html

In IE my website links are all functional but in other browsers when I click on one link then all links on a webpage become visited links.

```
Here is CSS:

@charset "utf-8";
.css {
}
html, body {
        background-color:#d8e9f6;
        text-align:center;
margin:0 auto; 
width: 800px;
}

a.nav2:link { color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 20px; text-decoration: none;}
a.nav2:visited { color: #EA5421;}
a.nav2:hover { color: #EA5421; text-decoration: underline; }
a.nav2:active {color: #EA5421; text-decoration: underline;} 


a.nav1:link {   font-size: 16px;    color: #EA5421; }
a.nav1:visited {    color: #EA5421; }
a.nav1:hover {color: #EA5421; }
a.nav1:active {color: #EA5421; }



#center {width: 800px; margin:0 auto; }

#menu1 {width:792px;
 }
#nav_text {width:590px; height:210px; background-color:#f39e81; float:left; margin:8px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; 

}

#nav_text2 {width:590px; height:210px; background-color:#509aca; float:left; margin:8px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;

 }
#nav_desno {width:170px; height:700px; background-color:#c0e3fd; float:right ; margin:8px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
#razmak {width:800px; height:875px; float:left; background-image: url(slike/pozadina.jpg);}


.wrapper_menu {background-color:#1d6594; margin:8px; width:780px; text-align:center
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;}

.nav ul {
   list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    }

.nav ul li {
    display: inline;

}
h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration:none
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}
```

Comment: Visited links are default functionality.  You can specify your visited links `:visited` the same as your `a` class so you won't see them any different when they become visited as opposed to being un-visited.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why all links are getting the visited state if you click just one is, that all links go to the same address: "#".

Comment: Yes, the problem was because all links pointed to the same address. Thanks you for this.